# Generate unique id that is not easily geussed

Tags: uuid, identifier

I have a system where the users can view ids of rows in a database. i.e. `https://www.example.com/user?id=1`

Currently it's auto incremented so it's fairly easy to guess the ids. While I don't believe this exposes any risk, I've been advised it'd be best to make them less easy to geuss. Something like `913458ugfg444` or something like that.

Now, to generate an id like this, you'd need to make it and then confirm in your database that it is already not taken and then repeat the process if it is. I'm not a big fan of this since it requires additional resources.

Is there a way that I can generate unique ids without the chance of multiple try/catches on the database and that are not easily geussable?

Comment: What's wrong with a UUID?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Have been looking at that for a bit. However I'm unsure about collisions  and how frequent they are.

Comment: Yes, there is an extremely low possibility of collisions. But the chance is so low that you don't need to worry (_if_ you are using a proper implementation)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name great! I think that'll do then. Can you put your comment as an answer?